# Widget similar to Android context menu

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I would like to have a widget similar to android context menu on every listview item.

I have a listview and on every item is on the right site a button (3 dots), where the user should open a popup menu for this item.

[image]

In the end it should look like this image

[image]

I tryed it with PopupMenu, but i didn't get it.

Does someone can give me a hint how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why it didn't work with PopupMenu?

Comment: Or does someone know how to open the listview context menu when this button is clicked and not from the long press ?

Comment: Hi, like @IdevDev has said, can you show the code about PopupMenu? So we can know why it can't work for you. If it can't work for you, you can use `PopupWindow` achieve the same goal. Show the codes, so we can help, otherwise, our answer maybe can't help you. Thanks!